# getting div id value using webdriver with java

Tags: java, html, css, xpath, selenium-webdriver

From the below HTML source I want to get the table's id value (`DataTables_Table_1`) under the priority section, because this id generate dynamically like (`DataTables_Table_1,DataTables_Table_2,DataTables_Table_2`)

```
<div class="box light detailsBox " id="priority" rel="Priority">
    <div class="box-content detailsBoxBody">
        <div id="DataTables_Table_1_wrapper" class="dataTables_wrapper" role="grid">
            <table class="ohim-table  dataTable" data-filter="" rel="dataTable1515477181791" id="DataTables_Table_1" aria-describedby="DataTables_Table_1_info">
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

below is my Java source code:

first I moved to priority div tag from that div, I moved inside the with class attribute

```
WebElement checPri = driver.findElement(By.id("priority"));
String insideDiv = checPri.findElement(By.className("dataTables_wrapper")).getAttribute("id");
```

I'm getting the output but not as expected one, because className applied multiple times, so its pick some other id not pick under the priority div.

Please guide me.

Comment: can you println your variable? ``String insideDiv`` ?

Comment: Yes, getting DataTables_Table_1_wrapper not getting the table id, so how can i include the table tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrive the table `id` values (e.g. `DataTables_Table_1`) under the priority section you can use the following line of code :

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='priority']//table[@class='ohim-table  dataTable']")).getAttribute("id"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `cssSelector` to specify the the path

```
WebElement checPri = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#priority .dataTables_wrapper"));
String insideDiv = checPri.getAttribute("id");
```

Or to look for an element with class `dataTables_wrapper` and partial id `DataTables_Table`

```
WebElement checPri = driver.findElement(By.id("priority"));
String insideDiv = checPri.findElement(By.cssSelector("[id*='DataTables_Table'].dataTables_wrapper")).getAttribute("id");
```